# Lipschitz constant of exponential map

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesics

I asked before this question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164336/lipschitz-constant-of-the-exponential-map) but I was not able to work out the details on my own.

Suppose $M$ is a smooth compact Riemannian manifold, take $p \in M$ and consider the map
$$ T_pM \ni v \mapsto \exp_p(tv)\in M $$
where $t \in (0, \text{inj}(M))$ is a fixed parameter and $\text{inj}(M)$ is the (positive) injectivity radius of $M$.

Is is true that this map in Lipschitz uniformly in $p$? More precisely, is it possibile to prove that there exist $\delta>0$ and $C>0$ s.t. 
$$d(\exp_p(tv_1), \exp_p(tv_2)) \le Ct \|v_1-v_2\|_p $$

for every $v_1, v_2 \in T_pM$, $p \in M$ and $t \in (0, \delta)$? Clearly with $d$ I mean the Riemannian distance on $M$ and with $\| \cdot \|_p$ the norm in $T_pM$ induced by the Riemannian metric.

Comment: Yes, the exponential map is smooth and therefore is Lipschitz on any compact domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am asking if the Lipschitz constant can be bounded from above by $t$ times a constant.

Comment: The parameter $t$ is irrelevant --- your question is equivalent to the following inequality $$d(\exp_pv_1,\exp_pv_2)\le C\cdot|v_1-v_2|.$$ If $v_1$ and $v_2$ lie in a compact domain, then, as I said, the inequality follow from smoothness of $\exp_p$. BUT if  $v_1$ and $v_2$ are arbitrary tangent vectors, then there is no such constant --- an example is a cone with slightly smoothed vertex and the point $p$ slightly aside. (Sorry I did not read the question carefully.)

Comment: Ok, now it is clear to me why $t$ is not important and the existence of such a $C$ is now clear to me. Suppose I consider the subset of $TM$ given by the vectors which norm is smaller or equal to $\text{inj}(M)/2$. For each $p \in M$ I will obtain a $C_p$ s.t. $$ d(\exp_p v_1, \exp_p v_2) \le C_p |v_1-v_2| $$ for every $v_1, v_2 \in T_pM$ s.t. $|v_i| \le \text{inj}(M)/2$. Am I able to say that $C:= \sup_p C_p < \infty$?

Comment: The constant $C$ can not be fixed --- consider Lobachevsky plane with constant curvature near $-\infty$. If you have a lower bound on curvature, say $\ge -1$  then yes --- you can assume that $C_p=\sinh r$ in $B_r(0)\subset \mathrm{T}_p$ if $r<\textrm{inj}M$. The latter follows from Toponogov comparison.

Comment: I think I do not completely understand your answer. So you are saying that, even if $M$ is compact, such a $C$ can be infinite?

Comment: No, for fixed manifold and radius there is a Lipschitz constant, but there is no way to make this constant fixed for all manifolds without additional assumption.

Comment: Thank you. The only point that is still not clear to me is, having obtained my $C_p=C_p(M,r)$ how can I make them independent from $p$? I think you are suggesting that it is possibile, but I do not see how.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I'm sorry if I bother you but can you explain to me how to conclude? I know that the exponential map is differentiable in a subset of $TM$ say $$A= \{ v \in TM \mid |v| < \text{inj}(M) \}$$ and that the set $$K = \{ v \in TM \mid |v| \le 3/4 \text{inj}(M) \}$$ is a compact subset of $TM$. If I had a metric on $TM$ I would conclude $exp$ is Lipshitz on $K$ but I do not have such a metric.

Comment: $\mathrm{T}$ has a metric induced by $g$. For the previous question: actually it depends on $p$, but if the manifold is compact then you can choose one $C$ for all points. Another thing $\exp_p$ is smooth even behind the injectivity radius so no need to use it unless you want to apply Toponogov.

Comment: Thank you. You say that, if $M$ is compact,  I can choose one $C$ for all points. How?

Comment: Just take the supremum; which is finite by compactness.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin You mentioned the constant for $exp_x$ on a geodesic ball of radius r about x if, $\mathcal{M}$ admits a lower curvature bound c, namely $C=sinh(cr)/cr$.  Are there estimates for the Lipschitz constant of its inverse $\exp_x^{-1}$ on a ball about the origin of radius R in the tangent space $T_x(\mathcal{M}$ (with Euclidean metric) given that M would be Hadamard with a lower bound c on its sectional curvature?

Comment: @ABIM yes, assuming that the radius of the ball is twice smaller than injectivity radius, othrwise there is a chance to shorter distance by going out and in.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Oh, then what is a good estimate on $Lip(\exp_x^{-1}|\overline{Ball(x,r)})$ for $r<2\operatorname{inj}_x(\mathcal{M})$?

Comment: @ABIM If the manifold has curvature $\le 0$, then the map is short. For general curvature bound it is true for a natural metric on tangent space with constant curvature.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Ah that's what I thought.  and this follows from Toponogov no?

Comment: @ABIM I would say Rauch.

Comment: Ah it's obvious now!  Thanks Anton

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the answer is positive. Let me consider an autonomous differential equation $\dot x=f(x)$ and let us assume that $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous. The flow $\phi(t,y)$ is defined by
$$
\dot \phi(t, y) = f\bigl(\phi(t,y)\bigr), \quad \phi(0, y)=y.
$$
As a result, we have 
$
\phi(t, y_2)-\phi(t, y_1)=y_2-y_1+\int_0^t\left(
f(\phi(s,y_2))-f(\phi(s,y_2))
\right) ds,
$
so that, at least in a coordinate chart,
$$
\rho(t)=\Vert\phi(t, y_2)-\phi(t, y_1)\Vert\le
\Vert y_2-y_1\Vert+ C_{\text{Lip}}\int_0^t\Vert\phi(s, y_2)-\phi(s, y_1)\Vert ds=R(t),
$$
and then
$
\dot R=C_{\text{Lip}} \rho\le C_{\text{Lip}} R. 
$
Gronwall's inequality implies
$$
\Vert\phi(t, y_2)-\phi(t, y_1)\Vert\le \underbrace{R\le R(0) e^{C_{\text{Lip}} t}}_{
\text{follows from Gronwall}}=\Vert y_2-y_1\Vert e^{C_{\text{Lip}} t},
$$
proving that the flow is Lipschitz-continuous with an estimate of the Lipschitz constant of the flow by the Lipschitz constant of the flux $f$ and time. Checking a linear scalar ODE proves that this estimate is essentially optimal. There are variants of this argument in the non-autonomous case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think I completely understand it. How is it connected to my question?

Comment: @Bremen000 $exp_p(tv)$ is the solution of a second-order differential equation with initial data $p,v$. Since a second-order ODE becomes first-order by increasing the dimension, your question is "How do the solution of my ODE depend on the initial data?" I gave above a way to get Lipschitz-continuity wrt to the initial data from Lipschitz continuity of the flux.

Comment: Thank you, now I see. The last part should be to express this in terms of the Riemannian distance on $M$. How can I do that?

Comment: I mean, now I know that there exists a constant $C=C(M)>0$ s.t. $$ \| \varphi(\exp_p(v_1)) - \varphi(\exp_p(v_2)) \| \le C \|v_1 - v_2\| $$ for every $p \in M$ and for every $v_1, v_2 \in T_p M$ sufficiently small. I used the notation $\varphi$ to indicate a coordinate chart around $p$. Now, how can I express the LHS w.r.t. the Riemannian distance between $\exp_p(v_1)$ and $\exp_p(v_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$
$\newcommand{\lin}{\mathsf{L}}$
$\newcommand{\et}[1]{\mathsf{T}_{#1}}$ 
$\newcommand{\ft}{\mathsf{T}}$
$\newcommand{\bxr}[2]{\mathbb{U}(#1,#2)}$
$\newcommand{\Ck}[1]{\mathsf{C^{#1}}}$ 
By compacity, we may take $\delta>0$ such that the exponential is defined on the compact subset of $\ft M$ given by $K:=\{v\in \ft M| \,\lVert v\rVert\leq\delta\}$. The map defined on the domain of the exponential by $v_p\mapsto \norm{(\exp_p)_{\ast v_p}}_{\lin(\et{p}M,\et{\exp_p v_p}M)}$ (i.e. the operator norm of the tangent map to $\exp_p$ at $v_p$) is continuous, hence its $\sup$ on $K$, say $C$, is finite. Then, for each $p\in M$ and for each $v_p,w_p$ in the open ball $\bxr{0_p}{\delta}\subset\et{p}M$, we have $$d(\exp_p v_p,\exp_p w_p)\leq C\norm{v_p - w_p}_p.$$

To see this, take any sectionally $\Ck{1}$ curve $\gamma$ on $\bxr{0_p}{\delta}\subset\et{p}M$ joining $v_p$ to $w_p$. Then $\Gamma:=\exp_p\circ\gamma$ is a sectionally $\Ck{1}$ curve on $M$ joining $\exp_p v_p$ to $\exp_p w_p$, whose length $\ell(\Gamma)$ is $\leq C\ell(\gamma)$. Thus, $d(\exp_p v_p,\exp_p w_p)\leq\ell(\Gamma)\leq C\ell(\gamma)$. Taking the infimum over the set of sectionally $\Ck{1}$ curves on $\bxr{0_p}{\delta}$ joining $v_p$ to $w_p$ yields the asserted inequality.